# I am having trouble with twitter api, it returns 400 bad request

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I am having trouble accessing the twitter api. It give 400 Bad request. Previously it was giving unauthorized exception. Can someone please help me figure out what am I doing wrong? I am writing this code for image upload. I thought I would first try with regular post method then would add file upload but stuck at Bad request

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import json
import urllib
import urllib2
from collections import namedtuple
import time
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac
import uuid
import base64


AUTHENTICATION="https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"
REQUEST_TOKEN="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
AUTHORIZE_URL="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"


CONSUMER_KEY=""
CONSUMER_SECRET=""
ACCESS_KEY=""
ACCESS_SECRET=""

OAuth_Basic=namedtuple("OAuth_Basic", "oauth_consumer_key oauth_signature_method  oauth_version")
baseString=namedtuple("baseString", "timeStamp string nonce status")
SendRequest=namedtuple("SendRequest", "method url timestamp upload")



def basestring(oauth, access_key, body=None):
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    nonce= base64.b64encode(str(uuid.uuid4().hex))
    basestring=percentencode("oauth_consumer_key") + "=" + percentencode(oauth.oauth_consumer_key) + "&"
    basestring+=percentencode("oauth_nonce") + "=" + percentencode(nonce) + "&"
    basestring+=percentencode("oauth_signature_method") + "=" + percentencode(oauth.oauth_signature_method) + "&"
    basestring+=percentencode("oauth_timestamp") + "=" + percentencode(timestamp) + "&"
    basestring+=percentencode("oauth_token") + "=" + percentencode(access_key) + "&"
    basestring+=percentencode("oauth_version") + "=" + percentencode(oauth.oauth_version)
    if body:
        basestring+="&" + percentencode("status") + "=" + percentencode(body)
    return baseString(timeStamp=timestamp, string=basestring, nonce=nonce, status=body)

def sign_request(signature, consumer_secret, access_secret):
    key = consumer_secret + "&" + access_secret
    hashed = hmac.new(key, signature, sha1)
    return hashed.digest().encode("base64").rstrip('\n')


def signaturebasestring(request, basestr, upload=False):
    if not upload:
        return percentencode(request.method) + "&" + percentencode(request.url) + "&" + percentencode(basestr)
    return percentencode(request.url) + "&" + percentencode(basestr)


def sendrequest(s_oauth, s_basestring, s_request, s_signature):
    oauth_header="OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\""+s_oauth.oauth_consumer_key+"\", oauth_nonce=\""+s_basestring.nonce+"\", oauth_signature=\""+percentencode(s_signature)+"\", oauth_signature_method=\""+s_oauth.oauth_signature_method+"\", oauth_timestamp=\""+s_request.timestamp+"\", oauth_token=\""+ACCESS_KEY+"\", oauth_version=\""+s_oauth.oauth_version+"\"" 
    headers = {"Authorization": oauth_header, "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Host":"api.twitter.com", "User-Agent":"OAuth gem v0.4.4", "oauth_consumer_key":s_oauth.oauth_consumer_key}
    status = {"status":s_basestring.status}
    encoded_args = urllib.urlencode(status)
    req = urllib2.Request(s_request.url, encoded_args, headers)
    try:
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        print resp
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print "httperror :" + str(e.code) 
        print e.reason
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print "urlerror :" + str(e.code) 
        print e.reason
    except httplib.HTTPException, e:
        print "httpexception :" + str(e.code) 
        print e.reason


def percentencode(val):
    return val.replace(" ", "%20").replace("!", "%21").replace("&", "%26").replace("/", "%2F").replace("=", "%3D").replace("+", "%2B").replace(",", "%2C").replace("-", "%2D").replace(".", "%2E")

p_oauth=OAuth_Basic(oauth_consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY, oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_version="1.0")
p_basestring=basestring(p_oauth, ACCESS_KEY, "hello world")
p_request = SendRequest(method="POST", url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json", timestamp=p_basestring.timeStamp,  upload=False)
signature=sign_request(signaturebasestring(p_request, p_basestring.string, False), CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_SECRET)
sendrequest(p_oauth, p_basestring, p_request, signature)
```

Comment: Check the response body, that usually contains a more detailed error message.

Comment: Thanks Cbroe, {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
 is the error that I get. Need to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: 400 usually means that you didn't log correctly or you are requesting for data that it is forbidden for you due to permissions. Yesterday it happened to me accesing a different service with an invalid Token. I hope that hint helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The percent encoding was happening in lower case, Changed to upper case and everything started working. There were couple of site that helped validate the OAuth Header.
Thanks